# Having CORS issues with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I have been trying to create a message program using node.js but am running into issues with CORS. I have a server file and a client file.  Live preview server running off port 5501 |
Server Code:

```
import { createServer } from 'http';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer);

// Define CORS options

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log('CORS middleware executed');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    next();
  });
  

const corsOptions = {
  origin: ['http://localhost:5000', 'http://localhost:5500', 'http://localhost:5501'],
  methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'],
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type'],
  credentials: true
};


// Apply CORS middleware to the entire app
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.emit('chat-message', 'Hello World');

  socket.on('send-chat-message', message => {
    console.log(message);
  });
});

const portHttp = 5000;
const portSocket = 5500;

httpServer.listen(portHttp, () => console.log(`HTTP Server listening on port ${portHttp}`));
io.listen(portSocket, () => console.log('Socket.IO Server listening on port 5500'));
```

Client Code:

```
 console.log('Client code is loaded');
     
            const socket = io ('http://localhost:5000');
            const messageInput = document.getElementById('message-input');
            const messageForm = document.getElementById('sendForm');
     
            messageForm.addEventListener('submit', event => {
                event.preventDefault();

                const message = messageInput.value;
                socket.emit('send-chat-message', message);
                messageInput.value = '';
            });

            socket.on('chat-message', data => {
                console.log(data);
            });
```

I can get it to work by using a browser extension to disable CORS but obvs can't rely on this. Any help would be great.

Errors:

```
 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:5000/socket.io/…' from origin '127.0.0.1:5501' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.


 polling-xhr.js:203 GET localhost:5000/socket.io/… net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)
```

Comment: Yes it is running on localhost 5501 through live server vs code

Comment: not sure how i forgot to add that haha. I get two but im sure the second one is related to the first one. 1: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OeVG_N6' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5501' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
2: polling-xhr.js:203     GET http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OeVG_N6 net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)

Comment: You should add the formatted error message to the question. It's not readable in a comment. Why do you use two CORS middlewares? Why `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');` and `app.use(cors(corsOptions));`. You should remove one. Why do you have two servers, `httpServer` and `io`?

Comment: I don't think it will work, but you should register all middleware on `app` before you create the servers. I don't know if that's a problem.

Comment: Have you checked the socketio docs on cors? https://socket.io/docs/v3/handling-cors/

Comment: I'd just be using HELMET for Node.JS, you can tune the requirements on headers as you go/etc.

Comment: Try adding `const httpServer = createServer(app);` after `app.use(cors(corsOptions));`

Comment: `from origin '127.0.0.1:5501'` .. seems right, since you haven't included `127.0.0.1:5001` in the `corsOptions.origin` array - also, you don't need to include `http://localhost:5000` since that would not be cross origin from `http://localhost:5000`